# Tomcat Logs on bluemix

Tags: tomcat, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Does anyone know how to get the logs from the Tomcat Cloud Foundry buildpack on Bluemix?

I need to access the Tomcat logs or the application directory in order to be able to see the logs that the application itself is generating.

Answer (score 3):

The stdout & stderr are routed to the console because the file system is ephemeral. You can view the console logs using the loggregator.

The easiest way to look at past logs is to do:

```
cf logs app_name --recent
```

To tail logs (stream):

```
cf logs app_name
```

Or click on the Logs tab of the application dashboard in the Bluemix UI.

To see the log directory in the Tomcat buildpack structure:

```
cf files app_name app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/logs
```

[CF logging](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html)

Comment: I get with the last command error 400, error code 190001. File error: Request failed for app: XXXX, instance 0 and path: app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/logs as the instance is not found.